# XSLT: how to copy the output of an identity transformation to an xslt variable?

Tags: xml, xslt

Using the following code I replace all the occurrences of the element QUOTE inside my XML input, with a String that is the value of the QUOTE/@ID attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="QUOTE">
      <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, I want to copy the output of the above transformation to a variable in order to pass it as a parameter in a template and then, apply an XPATH to this variable like so:

```
<xsl:template name="second-pass">
    <!-- variable which holds the identity transformation -->   
    <xsl:param name="pre-processed-xml"/>
    <!-- call SUMMARY template with parameter -->      
    <xsl:call-template name="SUMMARY">
        <xsl:with-param name="pre-processed-xml" select="exsl:node-set($pre-processed-xml)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<!-- SUMMARY template -->
<xsl:template name="SUMMARY">
   <xsl:param name="pre-processed-xml"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="$pre-processed-xml//SUMMARY"> 
</xsl:template>
```

My questions are the following:

1. How can I copy the output of the identity transformation to a
       variable?
2. How to call the "second-pass" template after the    identity
   transformation is finished and copied to the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is simply match the document node `/` and then store the results of `xsl:apply-templates` in a variable, which you can then pass to your `second-pass` template

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="doc">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:call-template name="second-pass">
      <xsl:with-param name="pre-processed-xml" select="$doc" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="QUOTE">
    <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="second-pass">
    <!-- variable which holds the identity transformation -->   
    <xsl:param name="pre-processed-xml"/>
    <!-- call SUMMARY template with parameter -->      
    <xsl:call-template name="SUMMARY">
      <xsl:with-param name="pre-processed-xml" select="exsl:node-set($pre-processed-xml)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- SUMMARY template -->
  <xsl:template name="SUMMARY">
    <xsl:param name="pre-processed-xml"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$pre-processed-xml//SUMMARY" /> 
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Having said that, this does seem a bit excessive. Given what you have shown in the question, you can achieve the same result simply by doing this....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//SUMMARY" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="QUOTE">
    <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```